# Bash create a tab delimited file with specific column names

Tags: linux, bash

I want to make a tab delimited file that will take inputs of the headings I want to be in the file. 
So I want to create a tab delimited file with column names "Onset", and "Duration"

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `printf "Onset\tDuration\n" > file`?

Comment: This works! What is the purpose of the "t' in front of Duration and the \n at the end?

Comment: `\t` inserts tab and `\n` inserts newline. See `man printf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output into `column -t` command.